# Can I detect if the auto return url option is on or off in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to check if the auto return url option is enabled OR disabled in my PayPal sandbox (business) account. Is there such a setting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about PayPal account settings

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check this with the API (besides trying a payment and seeing if it redirects you).

You would check this by logging into your account at sandbox.paypal.com